# Sending/Emitting an object gives [Object object] at client-side

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This node.js/socket.io multiplayer game requires that the server periodically send an object scene of type Scene to all of the clients.

```
io.sockets.emit("scene changed", scene)

function onSceneChange(data) {
    scene = data;
    //scene.getPLatformsList says undefined.
};
```

The Scene class is present on the client side also. However at the client side, printing the received object gives [Object object]. Trying to access any of the fields or functions says the object is undefined.

Scene currently only contains an integer value scroll and an array of Platform objects. Sending the fields separately gives the integer and an array of [Object object]s, which I cannot cast.

Currently the only way we can do this is by sending each literal individually. What is likely to be the problem here?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: JSON.stringify gives {} on the server side

Comment: in your code I don't see the full structure, if you could add more details ...

Comment: Actually, I think this identifies the issue - the fields are not public. I only use getters and setters, so the JSON string representation is empty?

Comment: yes, the object may not be updated in the right way, and as I said, I can't see what exactly happens there